# Why are items stacking with responsive css code?

Tags: css, responsiveness

I've got a portfolio page built in a grid. On a normal sized monitor and most mobile devices, responsiveness works well. Responsiveness breaks on certain mobile devices (Nexus 6P, namely), with the content stacking in decreasing sizes like Russian Dolls.

*EDITED: After a lot of troubleshooting and reading through other questions, I think it has to do with the original designer setting responsiveness with both em and px viewport sizes. Is this normal? I've added a link below to screenshots and the css files because there are a lot of different media queries that influence this.*

*EDIT: It only happens with a very small size window that seems to be where the 40.063em and ~<640px range media queries overlap. Also, it's proving difficult to replicate in simulators because if I open a smaller viewport first, then the Nexus6P size (or other sizes with width of 641px or less), it loads fine. It only errors when changing from larger viewport to one with width 641px or smaller.*

[Nexus 6P size, items stack oddly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMtk2.jpg)

I also followed another similar post's suggestion to use "white-space:nowrap;" and added that in the .work-item code and .work-item img. It changed the stacking (different items stacked) but didn't fix the problem.

**SOLVED: The HTML file for this module declared a medium-6 and large-3 grid size, but left small undeclared, resulting in awkward formatting.**

```
<div class="medium-6 large-3 work-item">
```

**I added small-6 to the class and adjusted the media queries to make things fit nicely.**

```
<div class="medium-6 large-3 small-6 work-item">
```

Thanks for the help! I learned a lot more about media queries and re-learned more about grids today.

Comment: Link to a fiddle/pen/bin that recreates the issue as best as possible. That way we can help you better.

Comment: Can you please add you relevant HTML to reproduce you issue?

Comment: @SidTheBeard, I tried replicating with a fiddle and couldn't get the responsiveness error to appear. The best lead I have at the moment is that the original designers set the responsiveness in both em and px units and they seem to be overlapping and causing the error but I can't track down the specific culprit. It also only happens in the simulators when I go from a larger screen size to this particular size. If I load the problematic size first, or a smaller correctly loading one then the problem one, it loads fine.

Comment: Did you copy/paste your HTML from your code base into the fiddle? At first it seemed like there was probably a closing tag typo causing them all to become children of the one that came before it. However, if you aren't having the error when you load the page in smaller screens it's not that. Copy your HTML that causes the error exactly as is and paste it here.

Comment: @SidTheBeard it won't let me paste code with more URLs in it since I have a new account here. I saved the HTML and added it to the dropbox link in my post.

Comment: @SonyaIverson Ok I will give it a look when I get the chance.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, I added the HTML as a file in the Dropbox link in my edited post, along with screenshots and the CSS files. If you have any insight, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score -1):

Use `clear: both` property after completing your section area, before your footer area. For adjusting device pixel ratio you have to use media queries in order to provide a nice cross-platform solution.